# How to create a cron job and remove job once run using php script?

Tags: php, cron

I want to add cron job based on record inserted time, After 12 hours, if once function run automatically remove the cron job based on php script is this possible?

actually i tried with below

```
$t=shell_exec('echo -e "`crontab -e` 30 9 * * * /path/to/script" | crontab -');
echo $t;
```

But nothing will work

Comment: Consider using a job queue instead

Comment: @Gordon job queue mean ? cron run each five mins?

Comment: Not sure if cronjobs are the right tool for this. Unless you have one script (running every minute) that handles all of your jobs

Comment: @kerbholz I already done that But my doubt is that way available or not directly add cron and remove?

Comment: Never needed to, no. And as I said, I think cronjobs are not the right tool for this. Cronjobs are run in the background _at regular intervals_. Adding a job, waiting for it to be done and then removing the job is (imho) not what cronjobs are for. Do as @Gordon said and consider using a job queue instead

Answer (score 0):

Below the commands u can use on the cli to add a cronjob to the crontab. But like Gordon mentioned before it makes more sense to generaly add a cronjob which than (every 5 minutes, hour etc.) checks your jobqueue for tasks which have to be started.

```
#write out current crontab
crontab -l > mycron
#echo new cron into cron file
echo "00 09 * * 1-5 echo hello" >> mycron
#install new cron file
crontab mycron
rm mycron
```

Comment: Their is no possible to directly add cron job? based on sql query insert time+12 hours

Comment: The method above works with a temporary file "mycron". You can achieve it in one line `(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "00 09 * * 1-5 echo hello")| crontab -` like you are trying. Try out the command without php first.

Comment: $t=shell_exec('crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "00 09 * * 1-5 echo hello"');
echo $t; I tried this but not working

Comment: Like i said - try the commands out on the shell, without php & shell_excec. If you're sure it works on the shell test out what happens when inserted by php. Questions like "Is your php-user able to use shell_exec" and so on should be resolved before thinking of the command itself.

Look here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115054/php-shell-exec-permission-on-linux-ubuntu